subquery as a join condition in databricks SQL unity catalog
My requirement is to convert an ORACLE SQL query to databricks SQL unity catalog SQL query. Databricks SQL doesnt support scalar subqueries as a join condition, what I need to convert is :


inner join `uc-dev`.iccu_dna.RtxnStatHist rsh
    ON r.AcctNbr = rsh.AcctNbr
    AND r.RtxnNbr = rsh.RtxnNbr
    AND rsh.TimeUniqueExtn = (SELECT MAX(TIMEUNIQUEEXTN)
                              FROM `uc-dev`.iccu_dna.RtxnStatHist rsh2
                              WHERE AcctNbr = rsh.AcctNbr
                              AND RtxnNbr = rsh.RtxnNbr)



I have tried to use CTE like so:


with 
max_rsh
as
(SELECT MAX(TIMEUNIQUEEXTN) as max_TIMEUNIQUEEXTN
                              FROM `uc-dev`.iccu_dna.RtxnStatHist rsh2
                              WHERE AcctNbr IN (SELECT AcctNbr FROM `uc-dev`.iccu_dna.RtxnStatHist)
                                AND RtxnNbr IN (SELECT RtxnNbr FROM `uc-dev`.iccu_dna.RtxnStatHist)
                                )



and later joining this CTE :


inner join max_rsh mtxn
    ON rsh.TimeUniqueExtn = mtxn.max_TIMEUNIQUEEXTN



Can you help me with this conversion?
I need to be able to replicate this join condition in a databricks SQL notebook for unity catalog.

You can try the below approach to databricks SQL:
SELECT *
FROM `uc-dev`.iccu_dna.Rtxn r
INNER JOIN `uc-dev`.iccu_dna.RtxnStatHist rsh
    ON r.AcctNbr = rsh.AcctNbr
    AND r.RtxnNbr = rsh.RtxnNbr
    AND rsh.TimeUniqueExtn = (
        SELECT MAX(TIMEUNIQUEEXTN)
        FROM `uc-dev`.iccu_dna.RtxnStatHist rsh2
        WHERE AcctNbr = rsh.AcctNbr
        AND RtxnNbr = rsh.RtxnNbr
    )

I have tried the below approach as an example:
INPUT tables:


WITH maxTime AS (
  SELECT
    rsh.AcctNbr,
    rsh.RtxnNbr,
    rsh.TimeUniqueExtn,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rsh.AcctNbr, rsh.RtxnNbr ORDER BY rsh.TimeUniqueExtn DESC) AS rn
  FROM table1 r
  INNER JOIN RtxnStatHist rsh 
    ON r.AcctNbr = rsh.AcctNbr
    AND r.RtxnNbr = rsh.RtxnNbr
)
SELECT
  r.AcctNbr,
  r.RtxnNbr,
  rsh.TimeUniqueExtn
FROM table1 r
INNER JOIN maxTime rsh
  ON r.AcctNbr = rsh.AcctNbr
  AND r.RtxnNbr = rsh.RtxnNbr
  AND rsh.rn = 1;

Results:

AcctNbr RtxnNbr TimeUniqueExtn
1   101 2022-01-01T11:00:00Z
2   102 2022-01-01T12:00:00Z
3   103 2022-01-01T14:00:00Z


In the above code a Common table expression (CTE) named maxTime is created.
The CTE calculates the maximum TimeUniqueExtn for each (AcctNbr, RtxnNbr) combination using the ROW_NUMBER() window function.
Then, the main query joins table1 with the maxTime CTE based on the account number, transaction number, and only selects the rows where the row number is 1 (which represents the maximum TimeUniqueExtn for each combination).
